# Return the biggest number in an array

Tags: c#

What is the perfect change for `&&` in my code? I don't really understand how to fix it. Here is the code of what I have so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class A3 : MonoBehaviour
{

    int[] arr = new int[3] { -7, 2, 6 };

    int reBig ()
    {
        if (arr[0] > arr[1] && arr[2])
        {
            return (arr[0]);
        }
        else if (arr[1] > arr[0] && arr[2])
        {
            return (arr[1]);
        }
        else if (arr[2] > arr[0] && arr[1])
        {
            return (arr[2]);
        }

    } 

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        print(reBig()); 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Try `arr.Max();`

Comment: @ja72 This looks like homework where it's unlikely that he's allowed to use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arr[0] > arr[1] && arr[2]` doesn't mean what you think it means. You're using it as if it meant "`arr[0]` is greater than both `arr[1]` and `arr[2]`", but it really means "`arr[0]` is greater than `arr[1]`, and `arr[2]` is truthy". To get what you wanted it to mean, you need to write it like this: `arr[0] > arr[1] && arr[0] > arr[2]`. The same goes for the other two similar lines.

Comment: Yep, it works! But now I've got the cs0161 error. Do you know why?

Comment: @АндрейРасскажи The compiler isn't smart enough to know that one of your 3 `if` blocks must be true. To fix it, just change the last `else if(...)` to just `else`, since if `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` aren't the biggest, then you know `arr[2]` must be without having to do any more tests.